# Static variables in Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, static, classloader

I have a jar in the servlet. This jar has a variable called 'projectDirecotry'. Logically, I want the 'projectDirectory' to hold different values for each user. Since the variable is made static, I face race condition here. I know it is a bad design to use static variables but I dont have any control over the source code of this jar. I found that the scope of the static variable is limited to the classloader. I'm just wondering if it is possible to create a different classloader to this jar for each user so that the static variable is no longer shared by the users.

Comment: May not be what you want but you could consider a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Comment: That will be a huge performance hit to create a new classloader for each user.

Comment: Is there any other way to make static variable non-shareable among the users?

Comment: What is the library actually used for?

Comment: Show the code that uses that static variable maybe we can give you better answer.

Comment: This library was developed by the cmu team for developing cognitive tutors

Comment: Hello, you can create a map <user,  directory> in servlet and copy value of static variable to map. Please, post code, it's difficult​ to understand  the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Any* member variable in a servlet is discouraged, because there typically will be only one servlet object ever. **All** of the state needs to go into the request/response objects, not in the servlet.

It sounds like you have to run buggy code, are not able/allowed to fix it, but still should make it work. The way to make it work is to fix the original code, not to muck with classloading mechanics or anything else.

Run!

If you don't, and somehow magically fix *this* issue: Where there is a fundamental bug of this class, there are more. In the end, *you* will be the one who is blamed for any future misfunction, because you built an absolute nonstandard infrastructure.

Imagine the next problem to be a performance problem. Or another member variable, XSS, CSRF. The probability is high, if you're now struggling with a static variable in a servlet.

Fix it at the root, or run away. Resist any second-class workaround, for any price.